# what is the iPad mini screen resolution or frame size?

Tags: ios

Interviewer ask me about resolution  or bounds of *ipad* mini? is it same as `Ipad` 2?
Or what is the exact answer for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

screen resolution for IPAD mini is 1,024×768

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has the same resolution as the iPad 2 and original iPad, 1024 x 768.

Answer (score 0):

If you need in terms of `frame/bounds` then :

```
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```